# Is it safe to use this way to pass context to non-context classes

Tags: java, android, android-context

I have read several articles about passing context to adapter or something else and i made some kind of contextholder for getting application context:

```
import android.content.Context;

public class ContextHolder {
    private static ContextHolder ourInstance = new ContextHolder();
    private Context context;

    public static ContextHolder getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private ContextHolder() {
        context = null;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Context getApplicationContext(){
        return context;
    }
}
```

then in MainActivity i`m creating ContextHolder object and setting context like this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ContextHolder contextHolder = ContextHolder.getInstance();
        contextHolder.setContext(this.getApplicationContext());
    }
```

in some other class, where i need to use contex:

```
ContextHolder contextHolder = ContextHolder.getInstance();
Resources resources = contextHolder.getApplicationContext().getResources();
```

The question is, am i doing right thing?
Can it cause memory leaks or other nasty stuff?

Comment: This will leak the Context. You could use a WeakReference in ContextHolder, though.

Comment: Doesn`t application context live through all application lifecycle?

Comment: Oh yes. My bad. On second sight I saw that you use the ApplicationContext. Nevermind my comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> in MainActivity i`m creating ContextHolder

But what for? [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is subclass of Context already:

```
java.lang.Object
  ↳ android.content.Context
    ↳ android.content.ContextWrapper
      ↳ android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
        ↳ android.app.Activity
```

so you could just use `this` (or `MainActivity.this`). Not to mention `contextHolder` variable you put your holder object in shown code is of local scope and visible in `onCreate()` only.

> Can it cause memory leaks or other nasty stuff?

I recommend using LeakCanary to catch catch all the memory leaks in your code. See: https://github.com/square/leakcanary

> In some other class, where i need to use contex:

```
ContextHolder contextHolder = ContextHolder.getInstance();
Resources resources = contextHolder.getApplicationContext().getResources();
```

This is all unnecessary and over-engineered. If all you need to get the application context, subclass `Application` class:

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
    protected static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();

       mContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
       return mContext;
    }
}
```

set it as your app application class in Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
```

and then whenever you need the context you can't get other way, can just call:

```
MyApplication.getAppContext();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach for holding a reference to an application context is fine. As [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) says that:

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way.

Thus, just for grabbing a reference to your application context, you should not subclass the Application class.

In your case, you should initialize your singleton in the first activity's `onCreate` method so that you should pass `this.getApplicationContext()` to your singleton to hold. For example:

```
public class ContextHolder {
    private static ContextHolder ourInstance;
    private Context context;

    public static ContextHolder getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public static void init(Context context){
        ourInstance = new ContextHolder(context);
    }

    private ContextHolder(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Context getApplicationContext(){
        return context;
    }
}
```

In your first Activity's `onCreate` :

```
ContextHolder.init(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: While extending Application object just for context holder may look odd, it's not true that you "normally no need to subclass Application". Apparently all my apps are not normal...Anyway, there's also no directbenefit from having ContextHolder modular (not to mention this approach requires implicit initialization. It's basically no point of having this class at all.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski You are absolutely right. However it is up to the OP to choose which is the best fit for his purposes. In my opinion the OP's approach (i.e. singleton class) is better than yours, because it is more compatible with [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and separation of duties principles. Also I think this class has no much overloads at run-time.

Comment: Sure, we can ignore overhead. I am discussing implementation now. The point is that in this approach you must implicitly initialize the singleton. Where you gonna do that - in MainActivity onCreate? Ok, but what if you go to another activity? you will init it again? No. duplicated  code and it easy to assume it should initialized already. Now - what if your app is killed and then user returns to it later, so it will be recreated. What will holder return when asked for context? `null`, because it will simply not be initialized -> NPE. You can always extend application to init holder there :)))

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I didn't take this into account (killing app by Android). Now, I should admit that your way is better than mine. Thanks Marcin for this point. +1